# Can I use Artifactory with Python PIP?

Tags: python, pip, artifactory

Can I pull Python artifacts from Artifactory using Pip?

I see that I can place artifacts in Artifactory using Python, but what if I want to pull artifacts from it using pip?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Support for  python pip was introduced in the Artifactory release version 3.4
Check their wiki for details regarding implementation: http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/PyPI+Repositories

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any specific information about the PIP's wire-protocol (frankly, I didn't search too much, just Googled it), but if it uses plain HTTP you should be just fine. Figure out what's the layout that PIP uses for its artifacts, upload them in that way, and it should work.

Comment: My question is regards to using pip to pull from artifactory, not pushing. Pushing doesnt require pip and can be done with artifactory's REST API. I need to know whether I can set up Artifactory as though it were a PIP repository and pull in libraries stored in Artifactory as I would with other Python libraries.

Comment: Once you are pushing the artifacts in correct layout, the Pip will be able to pull them.

Comment: @JBaruch: at least there is pypi simple protocol, mostly artifactory shall reindex the packages, it will be difficult to do this outside. And I saw you created ticket https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-5163

Comment: Yup, pypi support is on its way.